# Failed to load resource - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'adGallery'

Tags: jquery, css, gallery

from two days that I'm trying to run the jquery plugin "[ad-gallery](http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/)"  on my site, but to no avail..
I state that I am a novice in javascript and css languages, so the error could also be silly.

The interesting thing is that the plugin works fine locally, but once uploaded online (I tried it on different hosts) gives the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource http://sp1der.altervista.org/examples/js/ad-gallery.min.js
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'adGallery' index2.html:41
```

I checked on the project website in search of the same error, but it seems to be a problem only mine.

This is my index page: http://sp1der.altervista.org/examples/index2.html

Do you have any idea?
Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

All my errors in the log are related to `jQuery` not being loaded.

At least this line must be uncommented:

```
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
```

Comment: No, I'm sorry, this is an error of last upload..Check now please!

Comment: I am not getting an error now at all. Only the loader.gif can not be found, otherwise the gallery works fine.

Comment: :O is a problem of AdBlock Plus!
There is this filter in EasyList: /ad-gallery.$~stylesheet

Comment: Haha really? I heard from a friende parts of his website was removed by an ad-block extension due to his class names `advert` and `advert-row` etc.

Comment: Incredible..At the end, I have solved renaming .css and .js from "ad-gallery" to "gallery".
However, thank you so much :)